# Every process I start, apart from nginx, dies after a few hours on AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance

Tags: ubuntu, process, gnu-screen

I'm new to ubuntu (coming from mac) and I'm trying to run a couple of java servers and a node server on an ubuntu Amazon EC2 instance.

I run each server in its own `screen` session, and everything works fine for a few hours, even after I `exit` from the ssh session.

After a few hours, my site goes down. I ssh back into the server and all the screen sessions are just gone, along with the servers which were running inside of them. `screen -ls` just says there are no sockets.

Nginx is the only process I started which remains running.

I know there may be some hard upper limits on memory for processes, but I don't know how to change this, or how to diagnose if this is the issue. In any case, it seems odd that all my processes breach this limit - the node one in particular holds next to nothing in memory.

I've looked through `dmesg`, and grepped for 'kill process' and the names of my servers and the like, but nothing comes back and I can't see anything obvious by manually reading the output of `dmesg`.

I'm at a loss as to why this would be happening, again I'm completely new to ubuntu servers and probably making some idiot newbie mistake - this is just a blank EC2 micro instance (free tier) with nothing installed on it but nginx, node, git, and my servers.

If you were me, what diagnosis would you perform next to find the issue?